# Does Groovy have a short if form to call a method and not return a value? (not ternary)

Tags: groovy

I just want to *call* a method if a condition is met, in Python I'd do the following:

```
print_static_content() if condition
```

Could this be achieved with groovy?

Footnote: I know Groovy has a ternary operator but this returns a value.

Comment: `if (condition) print_static_content()`

Comment: Just what I needed, i was trying: `message ? System.err.println(message)`.

@JB Nizet add it as an answer and I'll mark your solution the correct one.

Comment: you can also do `condition && print_static_content()` if you're feeling weird...  @JBNizet's answer is better though ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates that would not return a value?, when it resolves the call?.
But, is nice to know it, could be helpful in the future ;)